# Sunspot not working with You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr serve error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I am trying to start the sunspot_solr but it is giving me the following error

```
Sunspot::Solr::Server::JavaMissing: You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr server
```

I have java runtime on my mac and I have tried searching on stack overflow but could not get any solution.

```
Saurabhs-MacBook-Pro% java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Saurabhs-MacBook-Pro% bundle exec rake --execute 'puts `which java`'
/usr/bin/java

Saurabhs-MacBook-Pro% which java                                    
/usr/bin/java
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solr has started working after re-installing jre 7 and jdk 7. It might be because earlier I had openJDK and now I have switched to oracle.

Answer (score 6):

I had Similar situation where I got that error message, but I

1. Installed JDK8 from:
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. And I re-run `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`
3. Then I got `Successfully started Solr ...`

Comment: this totally fixed it for me too.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to restart after installing.